# Computing VaR in a Monte Carlo simulation (question from Joshi's book)

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, derivatives, value-at-risk

I am studying Joshi's book on C++ for derivatives pricing. I am at chapter 5 on implementing a statistics gatherers class to use in a (simple) MC routine for pricing vanilla options, where it is assumed that the underlying follows GBM. My question concerns one of the exercises where it is asked to compute the Value at risk for a sample. I am confused about what this is actually asking.

My basic guess would be this: for each path compute the difference of the final value of the option and the initial value. Then collect all the information together and run some statistics to calculate the VaR based on that data. But this doesn't really seem correct...

Any thoughts?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose for concreteness that you're generating 50,000 possible P&L's, and you're looking for the worst 1%. You only need to remember at one time the P&L's of the worst-case tail, which is 1% $\times$ 50,000 = 500 P&L's.

You do need to reprice your book under each of the 50,000 scenarios. Ideally, you should fully reprice using the same calculation that you use to mark to market. However, if this takes too much calculation, then there are shortcuts to get faster but less accurate P&L estimates, but you definitely must not use delta-gamma.

For every P&L, if it is better than your current 500th worst, then just discard it and go to the next scenario. If it is worse, then insert the new P&L in your worst-case tail and discard the 501st worst (previous 500th worst).

Once you have compared all 50,000 P&Ls, the 500th worst is the VaR. You can also use the entire worst-case tail to calculate the expected shortfall (ES).